# Getting the Parent Tweet Id from a Reply

Tags: twitter, bots, twitter-api-v2

I am currently looking at the Twitter API documentation but I cannot find the exact keyword for the approach from which I am trying to get the parent tweet id for a Twitter bot that I am creating.

For example, if I want to automate bookmarking a tweet (eg similar to @SaveToNotion), if I reply to that tweet tagging the bot (eg @SaveToNotion), the bot would be able to get the direct link/id of the "parent tweet" and save it somewhere. I am trying to look at the [Conversation API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id) but I don't have access or how to retrieve the conversation Id from a replied tweet

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add example code of what's not working in your question? Particularly what parameters you send to Twitter API and the reponse.